# not able to execute between date jpa data with query annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotation to populate result set using spring jpa data. I have a `billing history` table with a column `creationdate`. I want to use `sql` `date between` query using `@Query` annotation. Below is my code:

```
@Query( "SELECT billhistory FROM BillingHistory billhistory INNER JOIN billhistory.userInfo user WHERE user.userName = :username AND billhistory.creationdate between :from and :to" )
List<BillingHistory> getBillingHistoryByUserNameAndDate( @Param("username") String username, @Param("from")Date from, @Param("to") Date to );
```

here I have also tried `String` data type for `from` and `to` parameters. but I am getting bellow error in my `SpringBoot` application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billingHistoryController' defined in file [D:\newWorkSpace\JasperReport_project\target\classes\com\google\jasper\controller\BillingHistoryController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'billingHistoryServiceImpl' defined in file [D:\newWorkSpace\JasperReport_project\target\classes\com\google\jasper\service\BillingHistoryServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'billingHistoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.google.jasper.repository.BillingHistoryRepository.getBillingHistoryByUserNameAndDate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)!
```

*****EDIT*****

**BillingHistory entity**

```
package com.google.jasper.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@Entity
@Table( name = "billing_history", catalog = "radius" )
public class BillingHistory implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8329286536383150966L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO )
    @Column( name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false )
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn( name = "username" )
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "planId" )
    private BillingPlans billingPlans;

    @Column( name = "billAmount" )
    private String billAmount;

    @Column( name = "billAction" )
    private String billAction;

    @Column( name = "billPerformer" )
    private String billPerformer;

    @Column( name = "billReason" )
    private String billReason;

    @Column( name = "paymentMethod" )
    private String paymentMethod;

    @Column( name = "cash" )
    private String cash;

    @Column( name = "creditcardname" )
    private String creditcardName;

    @Column( name = "creditcardnumber" )
    private String creditcardNumber;

    @Column( name = "creditcardtype" )
    private String creditcardType;

    @Column( name = "creditcardexp" )
    private String creditcardExp;

    @Column( name = "coupon" )
    private String coupon;

    @Column( name = "discount" )
    private String discount;

    @Column( name = "notes" )
    private String notes;

    @JsonFormat( pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" )
    @Column( name = "creationdate" )
    private Date creationDate;

    @Column( name = "creationby" )
    private String creationBy;

    @JsonFormat( pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss" )
    @Column( name = "updatedate" )
    private Date updateDate;

    @Column( name = "updateby" )
    private String updateBy;

    public BillingHistory() {

    }

    public BillingHistory(Integer id, UserInfo userInfo, BillingPlans billingPlans, String billAmount,
            String billAction, String billPerformer, String billReason, String paymentMethod, String cash,
            String creditcardName, String creditcardNumber, String creditcardType, String creditcardExp, String coupon,
            String discount, String notes, Date creationDate, String creationBy, Date updateDate, String updateBy) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
        this.billingPlans = billingPlans;
        this.billAmount = billAmount;
        this.billAction = billAction;
        this.billPerformer = billPerformer;
        this.billReason = billReason;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
        this.cash = cash;
        this.creditcardName = creditcardName;
        this.creditcardNumber = creditcardNumber;
        this.creditcardType = creditcardType;
        this.creditcardExp = creditcardExp;
        this.coupon = coupon;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.creationBy = creationBy;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
        this.updateBy = updateBy;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UserInfo getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }

    public BillingPlans getBillingPlans() {
        return billingPlans;
    }

    public void setBillingPlans(BillingPlans billingPlans) {
        this.billingPlans = billingPlans;
    }

    public String getBillAmount() {
        return billAmount;
    }

    public void setBillAmount(String billAmount) {
        this.billAmount = billAmount;
    }

    public String getBillAction() {
        return billAction;
    }

    public void setBillAction(String billAction) {
        this.billAction = billAction;
    }

    public String getBillPerformer() {
        return billPerformer;
    }

    public void setBillPerformer(String billPerformer) {
        this.billPerformer = billPerformer;
    }

    public String getBillReason() {
        return billReason;
    }

    public void setBillReason(String billReason) {
        this.billReason = billReason;
    }

    public String getPaymentMethod() {
        return paymentMethod;
    }

    public void setPaymentMethod(String paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }

    public String getCash() {
        return cash;
    }

    public void setCash(String cash) {
        this.cash = cash;
    }

    public String getCreditcardName() {
        return creditcardName;
    }

    public void setCreditcardName(String creditcardName) {
        this.creditcardName = creditcardName;
    }

    public String getCreditcardNumber() {
        return creditcardNumber;
    }

    public void setCreditcardNumber(String creditcardNumber) {
        this.creditcardNumber = creditcardNumber;
    }

    public String getCreditcardType() {
        return creditcardType;
    }

    public void setCreditcardType(String creditcardType) {
        this.creditcardType = creditcardType;
    }

    public String getCreditcardExp() {
        return creditcardExp;
    }

    public void setCreditcardExp(String creditcardExp) {
        this.creditcardExp = creditcardExp;
    }

    public String getCoupon() {
        return coupon;
    }

    public void setCoupon(String coupon) {
        this.coupon = coupon;
    }

    public String getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(String discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public String getCreationBy() {
        return creationBy;
    }

    public void setCreationBy(String creationBy) {
        this.creationBy = creationBy;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

    public String getUpdateBy() {
        return updateBy;
    }

    public void setUpdateBy(String updateBy) {
        this.updateBy = updateBy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BillingHistory [id=" + id + ", userInfo=" + userInfo + ", billingPlans=" + billingPlans
                + ", billAmount=" + billAmount + ", billAction=" + billAction + ", billPerformer=" + billPerformer
                + ", billReason=" + billReason + ", paymentMethod=" + paymentMethod + ", cash=" + cash
                + ", creditcardName=" + creditcardName + ", creditcardNumber=" + creditcardNumber + ", creditcardType="
                + creditcardType + ", creditcardExp=" + creditcardExp + ", coupon=" + coupon + ", discount=" + discount
                + ", notes=" + notes + ", creationDate=" + creationDate + ", creationBy=" + creationBy + ", updateDate="
                + updateDate + ", updateBy=" + updateBy + "]";
    }



}
```

where I am wrong in this query.. need advice.

Comment: Looks like it may not be a valid JPQL query. Can you post your  BillingHistory 
 Entity?

Comment: what is data type of to and from in your pojo?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I have included entity class now.

Comment: I think I have figured out the problem, will soon comment.. I think its a silly mistake..wait..

Comment: What you posted here isn't your actual code. You are using `String` for all parameters, which doesn't match the types on your entity. Hence the generated query cannot be validated to be a valid one.

Comment: @M.Deinum no no bro, actually I am using `Date` parameter for both parameters i.e. `from` and `to`. I said I tried making them `String` but problem didn't solve. Actually the silly mistake was that : in Entity class I have `creationDate` variable where as in `@Query` annotation I was using `creationdate` see, its a `case` sensitive issue.. Now I have resolved my issue. thanks `stackoverflow` geeks

Comment: That is not what your error message is stating. Hence the code you posted isn't the code you used to produce the exception. Please for next questions include the proper exception belonging to the code you used.